# How to add list in list

Tags: java, list

I have in file this:

```
MERCEDES 320000 3.5 37000 ABS;GPS;RADIO
```

I want make from it object.
I do:

```
private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
public listOfCars(String fileName){
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

        String[] verse = null;

        int count=0;
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            verse = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            String[] components = verse[4].split(";");
            List<String> eq = new ArrayList<>();
            eq.addAll(Arrays.asList(components));
            cars.add(count, new Car(verse[0], Double.parseDouble(verse[1]), Double.parseDouble(verse[2]), Double.parseDouble(verse[3]), eq));
            count++;
        }

        sc.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And when I make toString I can see:

```
listofCars{cars=[Car{m='MERCEDES', c=320000.0, p=3.5, pp=37000.0}]}
```

But it should be:

```
listofCars{cars=[Car{m='MERCEDES', c=320000.0, p=3.5, pp=37000.0, [ABS, GPS, RADIO}]}
```

How can I do that? Where do I make mistake?

Comment: Show your class `car`

Comment: Most likely you have a bug in the `Car.toString()` which you haven't shown. I would step through the code in your debugger to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ABS {public ABS() {};};
class GPS {public GPS() {};};
class RADIO {public RADIO() {};};

class Car {
    public String m; //Brand/Marke
    public double c; //Kilometres/Kilometer
    public double p; //Something
    public double pp; //Something
    public List<Object> features; //Extras
    public Car(String m,double c,double p,double pp,List<Object> features) {
        this.m=m;
        this.c=c;
        this.p=p;
        this.pp=pp;
        this.features=features;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String s="Car{m="+m+",c="+Double.toString(c)+",p="+Double.toString(p)+",pp="+Double.toString(pp)+",features=[";
        for (int i=0; i < features.length; i++) {
             Object o=features.get(i);
             if (Object.getClass()==ABS.class) {
                 s+="ABS";
             }
             if (Object.getClass()==GPS.class) {
                 s+="GPS";
             }
             if (Object.getClass()==RADIO.class) {
                 s+="RADIO";
             }
             if (i!=features.length-1) {
                 s+=",";
             }
         }
         return s+"]}"
    }
}
public class App {
private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
public listOfCars(String fileName){
try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

    String[] verse = null;

    int count=0;
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        verse = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        String[] components = verse[4].split(";");
        List<Object> eq = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s:components) {
             if (s.equals("ABS") {
                 eq.add((Object)new ABS());
             }
             if (s.equals("RADIO") {
                 eq.add((Object)new RADIO());
             }
             if (s.equals("GPS") {
                 eq.add((Object)new GPS());
             }
        }
        cars.add(count, new Car(verse[0], Double.parseDouble(verse[1]), Double.parseDouble(verse[2]), Double.parseDouble(verse[3]), eq));
        count++;
    }

    sc.close();
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            listOfCars("list.txt");
        }

    }
```

Using strings :

```
class Car {
    public String m; //Brand/Marke
    public double c; //Kilometres/Kilometer
    public double p; //Something
    public double pp; //Something
    public List<String> features; //Extras
    public Car(String m,double c,double p,double pp,List<String> features) {
        this.m=m;
        this.c=c;
        this.p=p;
        this.pp=pp;
        this.features=features;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String s="Car{m="+m+",c="+Double.toString(c)+",p="+Double.toString(p)+",pp="+Double.toString(pp)+",features=[";
        for (int i=0; i < features.length; i++) {
             s+=features.get(i);
             if (i!=features.length-1) {s+=",";
             }
         }
         return s+"]}"
    }
}
public class App {
private List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
public listOfCars(String fileName){
try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

    String[] verse = null;

    int count=0;
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        verse = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        String[] components = verse[4].split(";");
        List<Object> eq = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s:components) {
             eq.add(s);
        }
        cars.add(count, new Car(verse[0], Double.parseDouble(verse[1]), Double.parseDouble(verse[2]), Double.parseDouble(verse[3]), eq));
        count++;
    }

    sc.close();
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        listOfCars("list.txt");
    }

}
```

Comment: How is this answering this question ? A lot of added lines here.

Comment: @AxelH : He didnt provide his car class.

Comment: So you provide it for him ? Unless you know him or the exercice, I don't see how you could be sure this is what he need.

Comment: @AxelH : Yes, I know, probably he would like to have the features as strings.Edited.